# Convert Vue2 component (factory) to Vue3 with render function

Tags: vue.js

I would like to convert an existing Vue2 component to Vue3 but I'm having problems. Basically what you see below is what I come up so far (with irrelevant code left out). I could share the Vue2 code as well but it does not look very different.

When running the app I get the error *Component is missing template or render function.* So what could be the issue here? Is it because there is possibly a different instance of Vue being defined with createApp?

I think the inner workings of the mounted and other hooks are not that important right now. What is puzzling me is that the render function is not even called. I checked that with a log statement.

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
const app = createApp({});

export default (Component, tag = "span") =>
  app.component("adaptor", {
    render() {
      return h(tag, {
        ref: "container",
        props: this.$attrs,
      });
    },
    data() {
      return {
        comp: null,
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.comp = new Component({
        target: this.$refs.container,
        props: this.$attrs,
      });
    },
    updated() {
      this.comp.$set(this.$attrs);
    },
    unmounted() {
      this.comp.$destroy();
    },
  });
```

It basically provides a wrapper to render components of other frameworks in Vue. It is used like this in Vue2 at the moment:

```
import toVue from "../toVue";
[...]
{ components: { MyComp: toVue(MyOtherFrameworkComp) }
[...]
```

Comment: How do you use this code? What you listed is component factory function, not a component.

Comment: What is `this.comp = new Component` supposed to be?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this helps. New Component creates a new instance of the provided component I suppose. I did not write the Vue 2 code myself.